unable to boot into rootfs after building uboot and kernel from source
I hope this is the correct sub. I am trying to boot into tinkerboard 2s (rk3399 SOC) by putting together uboot, kernel, rootfs based on the instructions provided by rockchip here. They mentioned to follow this flow (i am using miniloader approach to SD Card):

As such, I went to Asus github page to pull rkbin, u-boot, and kernel to build.
I have successfully build the uboot with:
cd u-boot
./make.sh tinker_board_2 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-

This generates uboot.img, trust.img and rk3399_loader_v1.30.128.bin.
I then created the IDBLoader image with:
tools/mkimage -n rk3399 -T rksd -d /home/rkbin/bin/rk33/rk3399_ddr_800MHz_v1.30.bin idbloader.img
cat /home/rkbin/bin/rk33/rk3399_miniloader_v1.30.bin >> idbloader.img

Kernel is straightforward:
cd kernel
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- tinker_board_2_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- rk3399-tinker_board_2.img -j16

After that I created rootfs with this guide.
So I have all the required images: idbloader.img, uboot.img, trust.img, boot.img, rootfs.img.
However, when I put them all together based on rockchip's docs, I am still not able to boot into screen. Any ideas what i'm missing?
I don't think it's even getting into the boot section because usually there will be a green light to signal that it is processing. but not in this case.
